# Connected system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

[image]

two bodies having masses M1 and m2 (M1>m2) are attached to the ends of a light inextensible stringpassing over a smooth frictionless pulley.when the system is released M1 moves downward and m2 move upwards with acceleration a.T is the tension of the string.

free body diagram of M1 gives that

unbalanced force F = Mg - T

my question is how the unbalanced force became the difference of the weight and tension? please give me an accurate answer

Comment: What do you think the unbalanced force should be?

Comment: didn't get what you are saying

Comment: You mean, how to solve the system?

Comment: By the way, the system you talk about is called Atwood Machine

Comment: Matteo can you please explain this to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the force on M1 has to be M1*g - T because the only forces acting on M1 are its own weight (=M1*g) pulling downward and the tension T pulling upward. The fact that one force is down and the other up explains why the total force is the difference between them.

To actually solve for T and A will involve analyzing both masses, and will produce 2 equations and 2 unknowns.

Comment: but instead of subtracting why can't we just add the total force?Is this because they are acting in the opposite direction

Comment: please answer fast sir

Comment: @anilbabu Yes, they are acting in opposite directions, so they need to be subtracted.